# Cannot Delete file from FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, delete-file

I use this code in my service to delete files from FTP. `FilesAddressList` contains list of files that I want to delete. It always return true but my files are never deleted!

```
try
{
  List<string> FilesAddressList = GetFilesListAddress(FileAddress);

      //Delete Files
      foreach (var item in FilesAddressList)
      {
          var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(FTPAddress + item));
          request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
          request.UsePassive = false;
          request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUsername, FTPPassword);
          var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          if (response != null)
              response.Close();

          if (!item.Contains("A"))
          {
              (new ClassA()).AddStatisticsInfo("Delete", 0, 3);
          }
      }
  retutn true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return false;
}
```

I traced it line by line but never found any problem! 
What is wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you get in the response?

Comment: did you include trailing slash in FTPAddress?

Comment: are you sure credentials are right?

Comment: @DovD. In `StatuseCode = FileActionOK` - or in `StatusDescription = 250 DELE command successful.` I think It's right.

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo Yes the address is like this "ftp://10.128.0.68/Folder1/Gate1/712001.jpg"

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes I'm Sure it's right